# Let $G=\langle \mathbb R \times \mathbb R, + \rangle$ and $H=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2>0 \}$. Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\langle \mathbb R \times \mathbb R, + \rangle$ and $H=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2>0 \}$. Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

It appears that the identity element would be the ordered pair $(0,0)$. However that would imply that $0^2+0^2=0+0=0\not> 0$. So does this mean that $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$. I feel like this makes sense, but I also feel like I'm missing something and I don't understand the problem. Any solutions, hints, and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that notation meant to mean $G$ is the group of all ordered pairs under addition ( and not multiplication)? Also, it looks like a different notation with the $\langle\rangle$

Comment: Your implication is correct. $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$ for the provided reason.

Comment: It's the notation used in A Book of Abstract Algebra. It is under addition.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976565/let-g-langle-mathbb-r-times-mathbb-r-rangle-and-h-x-y-y-2x-sh).

Comment: I wrote that question.

Comment: You should accept Noah's answer if you are satisfied with it or let us know what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by David Scholz, you are correct that this implies that $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$. I'm not sure exactly what further insight you're looking for, but one thing to note is that given $G = (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},+)$ has identity element $(0,0)$, any subgroup of $G$ must have that same identity element. I bring this up only to clarify that in order to prove that a **subset** $H$ of a group $G$ is not a **subgroup** (under the same operation), it is sufficient to show that $H$ does not contain the identity element of $G$.